# Problems uploading the binary of my app to the Apple Store (Unaccepted version of the SDK)

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I’m having a problem when I try to upload the binary of my app to the Apple Store. Once I upload the file, the following message appears at the top of the page:’The binary you uploaded was invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK.’

The thing is that I have tried with every combination of base SDK / Target deployment objective with both xcode 3.2.2 and 3.2.3 (that includes the new SDK4 – final version) and the message keeps on appearing every time I upload a file.

Does anyone know what SDKs are being accepted at the moment by Apple? What combination of Base SDK / Target deployment objective should I use if I want my app to run on the iPad (SDK 3.2) and iPhones with SDK > 3.1.3?

Might it be because I generate my distribution-binary using a simulator device instead of a real phone?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Best regards,

Jorge.

Answer (score 1):

> Might it be because I generate my distribution-binary using a simulator device instead of a real phone?

Exactly. If you're building for the simulator, you're building for an intel cpu, not an arm. You have to select "device" before building your distribution binary.

Comment: Also, make sure you build using your App Store distribution certificate. Using a development certificate or ad hoc distribution certificate will get you rejected as well.