# How to fix "Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK." error for distributing an iOS SDK 4.2 app

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, app-store, appstore-approval

This is very similar to a couple of other questions on stackoverflow, but they all seem to be from last year and referring to lower version numbers.

I have:

- xcode version 3.2.5
- A distribution build with Base SDK = Latest iOS (currently set to iOS 4.2), iOS Deployment Target = iOS 3.2

I've tried the following without much luck:

- [Deployed to a device (not the simulator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156115/problems-uploading-the-binary-of-my-app-to-the-apple-store-unaccepted-version-of/3468553#3468553)
- Setting the iOS Deployment target to 3.0, 3.2, 4.0, 4.1 and 4.2
- Cleaned my xcode cache
- Deployed through Application Loader and Organizer
- [Did a clean build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454250/apple-is-not-currently-accepting-applications-built-with-this-version-of-the-sdk/4454399#4454399)
- [Reinstalled xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454250/apple-is-not-currently-accepting-applications-built-with-this-version-of-the-sdk/4454327#4454327) <-- turns out this was the problem - need to check that it's the final version (ie, xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_final.dmg) and not the beta version
- Tried finding a version of the SDK < 4.2 to install, but apple seems to remove all old versions from their developer site

I'm sure [iOS 4.2 should be out of beta now](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3830545/111884), so I don't think this is the issue either.
Any other ideas? Is there any way of getting more information about the versions of the SDK that apple want?

Very frustrating indeed!

Comment: You did a *search* before posting a question!?! +1 just for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem yesterday and solved it by redownloading XCode from the developer center and reinstalling it. For some reason, the dmg file on my disk was from 19th of November (no, it was not a beta), and the release date of the SDK is 22nd on the iOS Dev center. Check if your local copy was downloaded before that. It just automagically worked after a reinstall. I built the binaries against SDK 4.2 and set the deployment target to 3.1 if that helps.

I am not sure at the moment, did apple rerelease SDK 4.2 with XCode 3.2.5 at some point without changing the version? Anyway, hope that helps, it worked for me.

Comment: Now that I browse the emails from "Apple Developer", it might be that I had 4.2 SDK GM seed. I don't think I ever downloaded non-final versions but it was a few months ago so I can't guarantee that.
Also remember to completely remove XCode before reinstalling, and after that clean the target and delete the build folder.

Comment: OMG, you are a saviour! I didn't end up downloading it again, but I realised I had downloaded it already - both the final and the beta - and I had installed the beta the first time I reinstalled =( Installing xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_final.dmg worked like a charm. Didn't end up having to remove xcode either, for it to work. Thanks again!

Comment: Please consider joining [the App Store proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) on Area 51.